# Is it possible to disable Steam Guard?

Tags: steam

Whenever I log into the Steam website or into the Steam client on my work computer (or other computer that I do not normally use), Steam Guard prompts me to check my email for a code before I am able to log in - as per below;

[image: Steam Guard]

Is it possible to disable this for both the Steam client and the Steam website? If so - how?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes it is possible - if you log in to steam you need to go Settings -> Account and you'll see Manage Steam Guard security click it and tick it off to disable.

[image: Steam guard]

Comment: Worth noting that it is a Bad Idea to do so and there are no downsides to Steam Guard minus some vague level of "annoyance".

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh I have it disabled tho, because for some reason the mail was sometimes blocked leaving me with no way to enter steam. Also it kept sending me the mail every day... dynamic ip sucks

Comment: True, sometime it will ask you multiple times for the same computer which can get very annoying.

Comment: @Lyrion my IP is dynamic and I haven't had to do the Guard thing in months.

Comment: that is a NICE freehand circle!

Comment: @kotekzot Strange, I kept having to do it everytime i tried to log on. But that is not the real annoying part, like guild wars did it too... the annoying part was the mail not getting to my inbox :p

Comment: Are you using GMail? I've never had such a problem with them.

Comment: @kotekzot Yep i'm using gmail. It wasn't in my spam folder either, it was just not there.

Comment: ATTENTION: You will not be able to trade on the Steam Market without Steam Guard on and its a big risk to your account security.

Comment: @Lyrion I have dynamic IP too, but only get a mail the first time I log in after reinstalling. The key is saved locally, so this should not happen. It does not depend on your IP.

Comment: @Assylum Yeah but it wasn't like that a few years ago, I had to redo it every time the ip changed. Now I don't have to anymore, it is on now. They also fixed the it not showing up in my mailbox bug :p

Comment: Thank you!  I don't care whatsoever about any of the nonsense on steam, and being asked every time I log in to go check my e-mail to play a game is annoying af.

Answer (score 0):

you have to go back to the Computer you used to enable the Steam Guard. Because, when you enabled it, you didn't unchecked the "Remember this computer member"

when you open your steam, go to Settings - Account - Manage Steam Guard - Deauthorized All Computers Now.

By doing this, you can open your Steam to any computers. (and eventually play DOTA 2)

Comment: Is the steam guard setting per-device or global ? I disabled it in the website and when using steam CMD it asked me for the code... *facepalm*